# C++ Postfix Operator Strange Behaviour in BorlandC++

Tags: c++, console, operator-overloading, borland-c++, postfix-operator

## Overloading problem.

I have tried to overload Postfix++ operator in a class then I saw a strange behaviour whenever I try to do this

`cout << oldValue <<"     "<< oldValue++;`

From the above cose the expected output should be the same, But it's not

The output is as following.

(oldValue) incremented by 1

And space

And oldValue

## Another example

I thought I have some sort of error in the overloading.

I tried this code

`int x = 0;`

`cout << x << "    " << x++ ;`

The output is

1    0

But it should be 0   0

I traced the code line by line but found nothing strange.

I seek a clarification for this strange behavior.

Comment: *But it should be 0 0* - Which part of the C++ standard mandates that?

Comment: borland-c++? Really? Please update to something from at least the past 5 years

Comment: @Evg, It is actually guaranteed to be `0 0` in C++17, but Borland certainly isn't offering that.

Comment: If you are still using borland C++ then it is time to stop using that. You can alwasy fall back on an online compiler like https://www.onlinegdb.com/. That way you can at least learn modern C++, also do not forget to tell your teacher this.

Comment: @chris Even so... I would still recommend not to mix output with side effects. The code that does something and the code that outputs should ideally be in a functions of their own (with the output functions only accepting const values)

Comment: Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B): Version 5.5, released 2000-Feb-16, is the latest stable release of Borland C++. If you are lucky, then, the best you could hope for is compliance with C++98. My sympathies, if you are stuck supporting a legacy project that can't be migrated to something newer!